# How to disable specific service discovery by Spring Cloud Gateway when locator enable

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I use Spring Cloud Gateway with `spring.cloud.discovery.locator.enabled=true`, but I have an SMS service, I don't want this service access by Gateway.
My config like this, but it not work, I also can access sms-svr by Gateway

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      routes:
        - id: sms-svr
          uri: no://op
          predicates:
            - Path=/sms-svr/**
          filters:
            - setStatus=404
```

My router rules like this:

```
[
    ......

    {
        "predicate": "Paths: [/sms-svr/**], match trailing slash: true",
        "metadata": {
            "management.port": "22020"
        },
        "route_id": "ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_SMS-SVR",
        "filters": [
            "[[RewritePath /sms-svr/?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]"
        ],
        "uri": "lb://SMS-SVR",
        "order": 0
    },
    {
        "predicate": "Paths: [/sms-svr/**], match trailing slash: true",
        "route_id": "sms-svr",
        "filters": [],
        "uri": "no://op",
        "order": 0
    }
]
```

It have same issue with eureka, I can access eureka by Spring Cloud Gateway, I also need disable this behaviour

---

Finally, I disabled auto discovery and add route rules for each service, but I don't think this is a great way

Answer (score 1):

If you have eureka as your service discovery, you can use Spring Expression Language in Gateway configuration using this property

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.include-expression
```

Check [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/appendix.html).

Its default value is `true`and therefore **your `SpEL` must evaluate to a boolean expression**.

You can see metadata in your eureka server under this URL `http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps` and you can use stuff from here in Gateway configuration using `metadata` [key](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#route-metadata-configuration). Something like

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.include-expression=<your SPEL using metadata object>
```